# how to use angular directives inside angular 1.5 components

Tags: angularjs, components, directive

How can I use an angular directive inside my angular 1.5 component. I have a angular-ui bootstrap tooltip that I want to use in my angular 1.5 component. Everything is working fine except that I pass is not displaying inside the tooltip.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code for this component?

Comment: Need to see some code in order to take a guess about what the problem is.

Comment: Please add some more details so that the question can be answered appropriately.